# ORA_00913 in a PRODUCT table (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00913

I am trying to insert some rows to a PRODUCT table and I get an ORA_00913: too many values
at first and third line, column 13

insert into PRODUCT (prod_id, group_id, prod_name, price)
values ('000004', '0000045666', 'lampaan', 95,15);
insert into PRODUCT (prod_id, group_id, prod_name, price)
values ('000005', '0000045667', 'golvlampaan', 111,55);

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert 5 values:

1. '000004'
2. '0000045666'
3. 'lampaan'
4. 95
5. 15

into only 4 columns:

1. prod_id
2. group_id
3. prod_name
4. price

Answer (score 1):

`91,15` should be `19.15`

`111,55` should be `111.55`

For example:

```
insert into PRODUCT (prod_id, group_id, prod_name, price) values 
('000004', '0000045666', 'lampaan', 19.15); 

insert into PRODUCT (prod_id, group_id, prod_name, price) values 
('000005', '0000045667', 'golvlampaan', 111.55);
```